# A grey stripe has appeared right above the nav bar

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-s-8, navigation-bar

This morning after some regular use a grey stripe suddenly appeared right above the nav bar. The stripe follows the nav bar, so if I collapse the nav bar the stripe is moved down to the lower edge of the screen. Se attached images:

[image: Regular nav bar]
[image: Nav bar collapsed]
[image: Swiping upwards on nav bar collapsed, causing nav bar to appear above the grey stripe]
[image: Clearly visible on the lock screen]

It's semi transparent and a nuisance...

The device is a **Samsung Galaxy S8 Plus**

Comment: Hi @beeshyams I uploaded another screenshot, Chrome has nothing to do with the error, just used it for screenshot background.

Comment: @beeshyams This has nothing to do with styling the nav bar. some bug has appeared and I wonder if anyone knows how to remove it, hopefully without reseting the device.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.

As a side note I work as a designer for a company with a dedicated Android app. The current builds from the development team are pushed to my device where I can test the builds and provide input.

In the latest builds from today the team had integrated a third party lib which produced a on-screen server communications log. This log appeared as a grey stripe wherever I was in the device without me knowing, and only started printing logs when I started the beta app.

So, no problem with Samsung on this one, I guess this is a problem no one else ever will encounter. :)